# json_encode without get_result()

Tags: php, json

On my web server i cannot use `get_result()` in my PHP scripts. I am getting the error **Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result**.

But `bind_result()` and `fetch()` works, but there I have to declare the different columns every time depending on the SELECT result, but I want it generic.

The closest I got was with the following code:

```
               function bind_result_array($stmt)
               {
                    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
                    $result = array();
                    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
                    {
                        $result[$field->name] = NULL;
                        $params[] = &$result[$field->name];
                    }

                    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
                    return $result;
                }

                function getCopy($row)
                {
                    return array_map(create_function('$a', 'return $a;'), $row);
                }

                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 1 as userId, 2 as message UNION SELECT 3 as userId, 4 as message");
                $stmt->execute();

                $row = bind_result_array($stmt);
                if(!$stmt->error)
                {
                    while($stmt->fetch())
                    $genericArray[$row['userId']] = getCopy($row);
                }

                echo "{ \"userId\": ";
                echo json_encode($genericArray);
                echo "}"; 

                $stmt->close();
                $mysqli->close();
```

The output of this is:

> {
>       "userId": {
>           "1": {
>               "userId": 1,
>               "message": 2
>           },
>           "3": {
>               "userId": 3,
>               "message": 4
>           }
>       }
>   }

Although it should be:

> {
>       "userId": [{
>               "userId": 1,
>               "message": 2
>           },
>           {
>               "userId": 1,
>               "message": 2
>           }]
>       }

How do i get this additional level out of the json response and make it an array in the json format?
Or is there any other way to get the SELECT result in json format without changing the code every time.

Comment: issue is in line `$genericArray[$row['country_id']] = getCopy($row);` there is no value for country_id in your result. Hence that ""

Comment: thanks for your comment. But it just made me realise that my question was not asked correctly. Actually my target is array in the json ( [ ... ] ) also. I guess, i still need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly setting your array keys in the following piece of code:

```
if(!$stmt->error)
{
    while($stmt->fetch())
    $genericArray[$row['userId']] = getCopy($row);
}
```

To get the JSON output you want you want to be doing the following instead:

```
if(!$stmt->error)
{
    while($stmt->fetch())
    $genericArray[] = getCopy($row);
}
```

If you were using the first snippet for de-duplication then I would actually recommend doing that in the SQL instead.